# Automatically restart process on crash in an Ubuntu docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, systemd, inittab

I have a process in an Ubuntu docker container. If it crashes, I want to restart it automatically.
What is the best way to go about it?
I checked systemd (which is the normal Linux method) but docker doesn't support it. inittab is also deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Docker offers such functionality, all you have to do is to define a [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/) for the container.

You should choose one of the available policies `no`,`always`,`on-failure`,`unless-stopped` and adjust your `docker run` command accordingly.

From docs:

> To configure the restart policy for a container, use the --restart
>   flag when using the docker run command

For your case, choose one of `always` or `on-failure`.

**Note**: The above is valid only if the process you have mentioned is the container's entrypoint.